# Instance member ‘____’ cannot be used on type ‘ScoreHistory’

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following variables from "ScoreHistory.swift":

```
// ScoreHistory.swift

var datePlayed: NSDate
var totalScore: Int
var totalAnswered: Int
var totalDuration: Int
var gameStatus: String
```

I am trying to display the data to "ScoreHistoryViewController.swift"

```
// ScoreHistory.swift

navigationItem.title = ScoreHistory.datePlayed
datePlayedLabel.text = ScoreHistory.datePlayed
totalScoreLabel.text = ScoreHistory.totalScore
totalAnsweredLabel.text = ScoreHistory.totalAnswered
totalDurationLabel.text  = ScoreHistory.totalDuration
gameStatusLabel.text  = ScoreHistory.gameStatus
```

but they are all in error:
    Instance member ‘____’ cannot be used on type ‘ScoreHistory’

What does that mean?

My ScoreHistory.swift's full code looks like this:

```
class ScoreHistory: NSObject, NSCoding {

// MARK: Properties

var datePlayed: NSDate
var totalScore: Int
var totalAnswered: Int
var totalDuration: Int
var gameStatus: String

// MARK: Archiving Paths

static let DocumentsDirectory = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("scores")

// MARK: Types

struct PropertyKey {
    static let datePlayedKey = "datePlayed"
    static let totalScoreKey = "totalScore"
    static let totalAnsweredKey = "totalAnswered"
    static let totalDurationKey = "totalDuration"
    static let gameStatusKey = "gameStatus"
}

// MARK: Initialization

init?(datePlayed: NSDate, totalScore: Int, totalAnswered: Int, totalDuration: Int, gameStatus: String) {
    // Initialize stored properties.

    self.datePlayed = datePlayed
    self.totalScore = totalScore
    self.totalAnswered = totalAnswered
    self.totalDuration = totalDuration
    self.gameStatus = gameStatus


    super.init()

    // Initialization should fail if there is no name or if the rating is negative.
    if gameStatus.isEmpty {
        return nil
    }
}

// MARK: NSCoding

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

    aCoder.encodeObject(datePlayed, forKey: PropertyKey.datePlayedKey)
    aCoder.encodeInteger(totalScore, forKey: PropertyKey.totalScoreKey)
    aCoder.encodeInteger(totalAnswered, forKey: PropertyKey.totalAnsweredKey)
    aCoder.encodeInteger(totalDuration, forKey: PropertyKey.totalDurationKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(gameStatus, forKey: PropertyKey.gameStatusKey)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    let datePlayed = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.datePlayedKey) as! NSDate
    let totalScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.totalScoreKey)
    let totalAnswered = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.totalAnsweredKey)
    let totalDuration = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.totalDurationKey)
    let gameStatus = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.gameStatusKey) as! String

    // Must call designated initializer.
    self.init(datePlayed: datePlayed, totalScore: totalScore, totalAnswered: totalAnswered, totalDuration: totalDuration, gameStatus: gameStatus)
}
```

Comment: Please add the code where you create or add data to `ScoreHistory`. It looks like you call the properties on the class rather than an instance.

Comment: @vadian I've updated my question with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your model design you cannot access a property on the class like `ScoreHistory.datePlayed`

You have to create an instance.

```
let history = ScoreHistory(datePlayed: NSDate(), totalScore: 0, totalAnswered: 0, totalDuration: 0, gameStatus: "started")
```

and call a property

```
navigationItem.title = history.datePlayed
```

Comment: I put the instance code that you gave me in `viewDidLoad()`  
but when I call the property navigationItem.title = history.datePlayed, it gives the error 'cannot assign value of type 'NSDate to type 'String?'

Comment: Because the `title` property of a `navigationItem` is of type `String` rather than `NSDate`. The easiest way to get a string from a date is call its `description` property: `history.datePlayed.description`